# IDE / Best known method for writing Hebrew documents with LaTeX

Tags: editors, ide, right-to-left, hebrew

I usually use LyX to prepare lecture notes, course summaries, etc.
The reason I use LyX and not LaTex directly is twofold -

1. I usually need to type in real time - summing a lecture. I think for this I'd still need LyX.
2. I write all these documents in Hebrew, and it seems to me that writing Hebrew documents with LaTeX will be a real pain (different direction of text, etc.).

So I'm looking to solve #2 - have you ever used LaTeX for a right-to-left language effectively? What IDEs support this? What do you do when you need to write a document in such a language?

Comment: TeXworks has right-to-left abilities, and the integrated PDF viewer gets you at least a very quick cycle of compilation and seeing the result. However, I don't speak Hebrew, so can't say that it definitely works.

Comment: No worries. The question seems important, needed love, and is well outside my abilities to address.

Answer (score 11):

I wouldn't necessarily say you need LyX for quick writing of documents/note-taking (it's more to ease the learning curve), but the following method should work well with either plain LaTeX or LyX I believe.

At present there exist the excellent [babel](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/babel.html) and `hebfont` packages. The combination of these two packages is likely the best option for typesetting Hebrew text. The former provides support for Hebrew characters/text encoding, RTL rendering, and switching between Hebrew/Latin/other scripts, while the latter provides a variety of fonts for rendering Hebrew characters.

You can turn 'Hebrew mode' on simply with the `\sethebrew` macro, and off again with the `\unsethebrew` macro.

Boris Lavva has written a [very useful guide](http://sites.huji.ac.il/tex/newlatex_usage.txt) to typesetting Hebrew in LaTex 2e, which should get you going. It would probably be fairly straightforward to set up a template for Hebrew documents. Apart from a handful of new macros to learn, you should essentially be able to use Hebrew in LaTeX as you would normal LaTeX.

Note: There is even a `hebtech` document class for preparing formal technical documents/theses in Hebrew, if you find the need.

Comment: I think this doesn't address Amir's question per se, as I find that it regards to the process of authoring a document more than than the LaTeX packages and commands to use. Also, `babel` does have numerous issues and Vafa Khaligi's `bidi` package used with XeTeX and `polyglossia` are probably the way things are going (see his answer below).

Comment: @Eyal Rozenberg: With all due respect, if it didn't address Amir's question, he would not have accepted it, and people would not have up-voted it. Case in point that you're wrong. :-P

Answer (score 4):

I don't write in Hebrew, but I do use Lyx!  The wiki has instructions on how to set it up for Hebrew at [lyx.org/Windows/Hebrew](http://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/Hebrew).

The URL says it's for Windows, but a quick check on my Mac shows that it works on other operating systems as well.

The link also shows how to set up a shortcut to switch back and forth between one language setting and another, so you should be able to do this in your lecture and go smoothly between English and Hebrew (if you need that).

Comment: I really don't like lyx!!!! It is my own prejudice, but I think it is halfway between Word and actual LaTeX, and I don't see it as an option.  But you got +1 from me anyway, as I think your answer is useful  :)

Comment: @reemrevnivek as I said, I already use LyX, but I'm looking for a solution to write in Hebrew with LaTeX.

Comment: @Amir - ...and this doesn't do precisely that?  I thought this was exactly what you wanted!

Comment: @Vivi - Yeah,  "WYSIWYM" definitely a hybrid between an IDE and a WYSIWYG editor.  I understand why you might call it something less proper, but it is useful in some situations, when you don't really have time for the compile-preview cycle.  It also cuts the learning curve down sharply for new users.

Comment: @reemrevnivek: it definitely cuts the learning curve down, so I think it is a good way to start learning latex!

Comment: @reemrevnivek perhaps I wasn't 100% clear, but I wanted to learn TeX/LaTeX and "program" in it directly, not in LyX (which was excellent for me, but I want to understand the inner-workings).

Comment: Lyx is great for someone who want to write Latex in Hebrew documents and is just learning Latex.  Best thing is the moment you go into Latex mode it automatically switches back to English and as soon as you leave the equation it autoswitches back to Hebrew - no manual language switching is great!

Answer (score 3):

I advise you to use polyglossia package in XeTeX. the bidirectional support in babel is not really powerful but you have bidi package for xelatex that is very powerful. bidi for instance allows you to typeset tabular RTL, you can have almsot any kind of link by usng hyperref package in RTL documents, color works almost works as expected, and bidi supports a lot of extra packages for example, you can use the wonderful wrapfig package in RTL documents by using bidi. Furthur, there are bugs in bidirectional typesetting bugs of babel that are fixed in bidi. As an Example, consider this minimal document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\input{rlbabel.def}
\@rltrue
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is a test
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

Gives:

[image]

but

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bidi}
\setRTL
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is a test
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

Gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As for engine, I recommend XeLaTeX with the `bidi` and `fontspec` packages or LuaLaTeX with `fontspec`. You can also use `polyglossia`, which works with both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. From my experience, XeLaTeX’s bidirectional and rendering support is superior to LuaLaTeX, which produces wrong parentheses and brackets and ugly nikkud.

You can see code examples by me here:

- https://xpr.digitalwords.net/ (books and booklets)
- https://ac.digitalwords.net/#theses-2015 (MA thesis)

I use (Neo)Vim for writing bidirectional texts for years now, and I find it very convenient. You can set `invrl` in order to change the direction of text in the current buffer.

```
map <C-Space> :set invrl<CR>
imap <C-Space> <Esc>:set invrl<CR>a
```

Answer (score 0):

The method I use is very effective.

Try this:

```
\documentclass[hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
טקסט לדוגמא
\end{document}
```

You can switch to other languages by using `\selectlanguage{<language>}`.

Comment: Does not work for me. Running vanilla LaTeX on Xubuntu 17.10 with TeXstudio. Get error: Font LHE/cmr/m/n/10=jerus10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \babel@aux{hebrew}{}.